# Создать datepicker для динамических элементов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker

Коллеги, прошу помочь с datepicker. На данный момент он активируется только для первой строки, а нужно для всех.
вот мой html:

```html
div class="caption">
     <div id="divAllowedApplications">
    <table id="conditionsTable" class="gvuzDataGrid">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Конкурс</th>
                <th>ФИО</th>
                <th>Согласие на зачисление</th>
                <th>Дата согласия</th>
                <th>Отказ от зачисления</th>
                <th>Дата отказа</th>
                <th class="editor_conditions"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="conditions">
            <%foreach (var item in Model.DataConsentToEnrollment)
                {%>                  
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function WzInit() { return false; }
            </script>
            <tr>
                <td><%=item.CompetitiveGroupName%></td>
                <%if (item.FullName == null)
                    {%>
                <td><%=ViewBag.fullName%></td>
                <%}
                else
                {%>
                <td><%=item.FullName%></td> 
                <% }%>
                <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $parent.selectedAgree" id="Agree" itemid="<%=item.IsAgreed%>"/></td>
                <td><label for="datepAgree">Дата: </label><input id="datepAgree" class="datepicker_recurring_start" /></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $parent.selectedDisagree" id="Disagree" itemid="<%=item.IsDisagreed%>"/></td>
                <td><label for="datepDisagree">Дата: </label><input id="datepDisagree" class="datepicker_recurring_start"/></td>
            </tr>
            <%}%>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
    </div>
```

и вот код для datepicker:

```
<script>
$("divAllowedApplications.datePicker").datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, showOn: "button", buttonImage: '<%= Url.Images("calendar.jpg") %>', buttonImageOnly: true, yearRange: '-10:+0', maxDate: new Date() });
$(function WzInit() {
    $('.datepicker_recurring_start').live('click', function () {
        $('.datepicker_recurring_start').datepicker();
    });              
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Может вот так?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#divAllowedApplications .datepicker_recurring_start").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: увы, все то же самое:(